# Convert non-ARC to ARC project without recreate it?

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

I'm just wondering if it's possible to convert a non-ARC project to ARC without recreate it at all ?
Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by recreate it?

Comment: This is a perfectly fine question to me. Voting up.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

With Xcode 7 you use the Edit | Convert | Convert to Objective-C ARC menu.

---

Pre-Xcode 7:

In Xcode, use the Edit | Refactor | Convert to Objective-C ARC menu. No need to recreate the project.

[image]

Comment: I never trust the refactor tool of Xcode );-o

Comment: Why not? As long as you preview the changes to be sure the correct changes are made, it's handy.

Comment: Because I have seen refactor fails when renaming variables... I can imagine that such a harder task could screw up your project easily with an incorrect references handling... But it's just an opinion ;-)

Comment: remember to create a snapshot before using the refractor and you will be fine

Comment: Xcode 7: Edit => Convert => Convert to Objective-C ARC...